# SQL window function to spread frame value

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a following table (Items):

| index (number) | type (string) | id (number) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Other | 2244596 |
| 2 | FrameStart | 888 |
| 3 | Other | 235235 |
| 4 | Other | 8957567 |
| 5 | Other | 14124 |
| 6 | FrameEnd | 0 |
| 7 | Other | 275823 |
| 8 | Other | 789798 |

Is there a way to add a 4th column with frame id if rows are between FrameStart and FrameEnd and null otherwise:

| index (number) | type (string) | id (number) | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Other | 2244596 |  |
| 2 | FrameStart | 888 | 888 |
| 3 | Other | 235235 | 888 |
| 4 | Other | 8957567 | 888 |
| 5 | Other | 14124 | 888 |
| 6 | FrameEnd | 0 |  |
| 7 | Other | 275823 |  |
| 8 | Other | 789798 |  |

I tried to do it like the following

```
SELECT 
index, 
type, 
id, 
CASE WHEN (type = 'FrameStart') THEN id WHEN (type = 'FrameEnd') THEN null ELSE LAG(test) OVER(ORDER BY index)  END as test  
FROM Items
```

but, of course, `LAG(test)` cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MT0 beat me to it with a better answer, but here's an option using windowed functions...

```
WITH
  framed AS
(
  SELECT
    items.*,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('FrameStart', 'FrameEnd') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY ix)   AS frame_id
  FROM
    items
)
SELECT
  framed.*,
  MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'FrameStart' THEN id END) OVER (PARTITION BY frame_id)
FROM
  framed
ORDER BY
  ix
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b8a0150b46315256f189506c5fb76fc5

Comment: The OP asked to "add a 4th column with frame id if rows are between FrameStart and FrameEnd". There may be an edge-case when there is a FrameStart without a matching FrameEnd and depending on the OP's requirements (which are unclear on this) they may or may not want to output the `test` value for those rows. This will output `test` values. If its not required the you could check for the existence of FrameEnd with `LEAD`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8151ec9a2ad4676db3f2782321ef98e7)

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12c, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       "INDEX",
       type,
       CASE type
       WHEN 'FrameEnd' THEN NULL
       ELSE test
       END AS test
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY "INDEX"
  MEASURES
    framestart.id AS test
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( framestart other*? frameend | other )
  DEFINE
    framestart AS type = 'FrameStart',
    frameend   AS type = 'FrameEnd',
    other      AS 1 = 1
)
```

*Or you can use `PATTERN ( framestart other*? (frameend | $) | other )` if you want to also match a trailing `framestart` without a `frameend`.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ("INDEX", type, id) AS
SELECT 1, 'Other',      2244596 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'FrameStart',     888 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Other',       235235 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Other',      8957567 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Other',        14124 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'FrameEnd',         0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Other',       275823 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Other',       789798 FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: do not use `INDEX` (or other reserved words) as column names.*

Outputs:

> | ID | INDEX | TYPE | TEST |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2244596 | 1 | Other | *null* |
> | 888 | 2 | FrameStart | 888 |
> | 235235 | 3 | Other | 888 |
> | 8957567 | 4 | Other | 888 |
> | 14124 | 5 | Other | 888 |
> | 0 | 6 | FrameEnd | *null* |
> | 275823 | 7 | Other | *null* |
> | 789798 | 8 | Other | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=db7aadbc598411a259d9b401d1981708)*

Answer (score 1):

If your `index` column is a true sequence, you may use recursive CTE (if not you must add extra row_number() column and use it).

You gies through the table on the `index` when you see FramaStart you keep the ID, when you see FragmeEnd you reset it, in all other case you copy the previous value.

**Example**

```
with t1 ( "INDEX", type, id, test) as (
select 
 "INDEX", type, id,
 case when type = 'FrameStart' then id end as test
from tab1 where "INDEX" = (select min("INDEX") from tab1)
union all
select 
  tab1."INDEX", tab1.type, tab1.id,
  case 
     when tab1.type = 'FrameStart' then tab1.id
     when tab1.type = 'FrameEnd' then null else t1.test end
from  tab1
join t1 on t1."INDEX"+1 = tab1."INDEX" 
)
select * from t1;

     INDEX TYPE               ID       TEST
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Other         2244596           
         2 FrameStart        888        888
         3 Other          235235        888
         4 Other         8957567        888
         5 Other           14124        888
         6 FrameEnd            0           
         7 Other          275823           
         8 Other          789798
```

Comment: Doesn't remotely do what the OP asked for...  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=50144ee09dab3228b3bff4bb3b6ab1ac

Comment: You are of course *locally* right @MatBailie but I guess a simple comment would be enough... BTW I changed my approach totaly.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, thank you! Your previous version is the only code I managed to make work so far (it appears to be Oracle 92, even WITH operator doesn't work for some reason). The only thing, do you think it's possible to put the frame id instead of 1 into the diff column?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it for Sql Server I think it will be similar in Oracle :

```
;with start_end_frames as
(
    select indx,type,id
    from Items
    where type = 'FrameStart' or type = 'FrameEnd'
)
, match_start_end as
(
    select indx, 
           lead(indx)over(order by indx) as nextIndx,
           type,
           lead(type)over(order by indx) as nextType,
           id
    from start_end_frames
)
, frame_intervals as
(
    select indx,nextIndx,id 
    from match_start_end
    where type = 'FrameStart' and nextType = 'FrameEnd'
)
select i.indx,i.type,i.id,f.id
from  frame_intervals f right join  Items i
on f.indx <= i.indx and  i.indx  < f.nextIndx
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the column, it can be updated via a merge.

The code below gets the first value of a calculated ranking.

> ```
> alter table Items add test number;
> ```

> ```
> MERGE INTO Items Tgt
> USING
> (
>   SELECT "index"
>   , FIRST_VALUE(CASE WHEN "type" LIKE 'Frame%Start' THEN id END) 
>           OVER (PARTITION BY Rnk ORDER BY "index") as FrameStartId
>   FROM 
>   (
>     SELECT "index", "type", id
>     , SUM(CASE WHEN "type" LIKE 'Frame%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
>           OVER (ORDER BY "index") AS Rnk
>     FROM Items itm
>     ORDER BY "index"
>   ) q
> ) Src
> ON (Tgt."index" = Src."index" AND Src.FrameStartId IS NOT NULL) 
> WHEN MATCHED THEN
> UPDATE SET test = Src.FrameStartId;
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from Items
> order by "index"
> ```
>
> ```
> index | type       |      ID | TEST
> ----: | :--------- | ------: | ---:
>     1 | Other      | 2244596 | null
>     2 | FrameStart |     888 |  888
>     3 | Other      |  235235 |  888
>     4 | Other      | 8957567 |  888
>     5 | Other      |   14124 |  888
>     6 | FrameEnd   |       0 | null
>     7 | Other      |  275823 | null
>     8 | Other      |  789798 | null
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69679510a2a40885bac3da80d0ea980b)*